# how to define history and match type(from React Router Dom) in React/Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-typescript

I have a project using React, React Router Dom(RRD), Redux and Typescript. RRD is by default passing the `match` and `history` props to my child component that I define in the Route component props(see below). Inside my component Redux is also adding two props to my component, a function(getPlaylist) and an object(auth).

Inside my component, when I come to type all of the props, I am having trouble typing `match` and `history`.

I've tried the following with no luck:

- RouteComponentProps with my custom props added
- importing `History` from RRD, like so: import { History } from "react-router-dom" and using it as a type (see my code)

My component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo, useLayoutEffect } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import CreatePlaylist from "../components/playlist/CreatePlaylist"
import { getPlaylist } from "../actions/playlistActions"
import isEmpty from "../utils/isEmpty"
import { Auth, Playlist } from "interfaces"
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router"
import { History } from "react-router-dom"

type EditPlaystProps2 = {
    getPlaylist: Function
    playlist: Playlist
    auth: Auth
}

interface EditPlaystProps {
    history: History
    auth: Auth
    getPlaylist: Function
    playlist: Playlist
    match: any
}

function EditPlaylist({
    history,
    auth,
    getPlaylist,
    playlist,
    match,
}: RouteComponentProps<EditPlaystProps2>) {
const [currentPlaylist, setcurrentPlaylist] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const { isAuthenticated } = auth

        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            history.push("/login")
        }
    }, [auth, history])

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        getPlaylist(match.params.slug)
    }, [getPlaylist, match.params.slug])

    useMemo(() => {
        const { isAuthenticated } = auth

        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            history.push("/login")
        }
        if (playlist) {
            setcurrentPlaylist(playlist)
        }
    }, [auth, history, setcurrentPlaylist, playlist])

    const editQupplistContent = () => {
        const playlistsHaveLoaded = !isEmpty(currentPlaylist.playlist)

        if (playlistsHaveLoaded) {
            return (
                <CreatePlaylist
                    name={currentPlaylist.playlist.name}
                    slug={currentPlaylist.playlist.slug}
                    id={currentPlaylist.playlist._id}
                    title="Edit playlist"
                    buttonText="Edit playlist"
                />
            )
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Edit playlist</h1>

            {editQupplistContent()}
        </div>
    )
}

EditPlaylist.propTypes = {
    getPlaylist: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    playlist: PropTypes.object,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    playlist: state.playlist,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPlaylist })(EditPlaylist)
```

Comment: Are you really need `connect` in funtional components? You can use `useHistory` hook, if you are need access to history, useSecector for your redux state, etc...

Comment: I have recently converted this function from a class based one to a function comp and wasn't aware of these hooks. So definitely don't need to use `connect`, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type Props = RouteComponentProps & {
  getPlaylist: Function,
  playlist: Playlist,
  auth: Auth,
}
```

like this?